# Personal Investment Account for US citizen residing in Canada

Tags: investing, canada, bank-account, rebalancing

I'm a US citizen residing in Canada.

Can anyone recommend a service I can use to manage a personal investment account (USD) under these circumstances?

I only need to deposit money once, and maybe rebalance my portfolio every 6-12 months, but even that isn't critical.

Vanguard and TDAmeritrade were not able to help me.

Comment: Do you want to invest in CAD or USD?

Comment: Why were Vanguard and TDAmeritrade unable to help you?

Comment: They just don't do it.  Too much legal hassle, I think.

Answer (score 1):

I use Interactive Brokers without any trouble. Since I signed up with my Canadian address I believe that I have an account with IB Canada, but I can deposit/withdraw/transfer/trade in many currencies, including USD and CAD, as desired.

Comment: I wasn't able to open an account as a resident of Canada.  In the second part of the account creation process, I got this message: "As a U.S person, you need to declare the U.S as a tax residency."

Comment: Well, it's true, you do have to file U.S. taxes if you are a U.S. person. If you try to avoid it then they are very right in not letting you open an account.

Comment: Yeah I wasn't sure how to interpret that.  I'm not sure what they mean "U.S person".  I'm not trying to avoid taxes.  I'm a student, and my income is low enough that I don't have to pay US income tax while abroad.  I've been operating under the assumption that I'm a resident of Canada (since it is where I am residing most of the time these days...) This whole thing would be a lot simpler if I were a U.S. resident, and it seems like maybe I still am?

Comment: Per the IRS: A U.S. person is "a citizen or resident of the United States". So you are definitely in that category. Your assumption that you are a resident of Canada is likely true, but you are still also (and always) a U.S. person.

http://www.irs.gov/Individuals/International-Taxpayers/Classification-of-Taxpayers-for-U.S.-Tax-Purposes

Answer (score 0):

eTrade does allow US citizens who live outside the country to open an investment account, although additional paperwork will be required.

Comment: I contacted them, and they said:

"Kevin M: Unfortunately, we are not able to offer services to non US residents at this time, I regret any disappointment."

Comment: That's odd because their financial policy indicates otherwise